# How do I ping someone in a reply to a command in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How I want my bot to ping people

[image]

I want to make it so that my bot pings people whenever it replies to a command, like how I'm replying in the image, with the `@ON` and not actually including a mention in the message.

I tried declaring it in the client options in the `index.js` file, but it doesn't seem to work.

**My `index.js` file:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Discord, Client, Collection, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const bottoken = process.env.token

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
client.commands = new Collection();

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client, MessageEmbed));
    }
}

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.login(bottoken);
```

**The command that I'm testing with (this is my only command, I want to make sure that stuff like these options work before adding more commands):**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!' });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CommandInteraction.reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) only replies to the [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction). You need to use [`Message.reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply).

---

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.content === 'reply') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'This is a reply.'
        })
    }
});
```

[image]